# Extract Data With Backslash and Double Quote - Python CSV Reader

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

Below is my code to extract data from a csv file (I got the file from dumpped mysql).

```
data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

After a few tests, I found that my code above has one big problem. it can't extract data such below:

```
"25","Mike Ross","Tennok\"","NO"
```

Any idea to fix this? TQ.

Answer (score 7):

The `csv` module expects the quote character to be doubled up by default to indicate it's a literal `"`, so it'll incorrectly delimit the fields...

```
data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
# ['25', 'Mike Ross', 'Tennok\\",NO"']
```

Use `escapechar` to over-ride this behaviour:

```
data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', escapechar='\\')
# ['25', 'Mike Ross', 'Tennok"', 'NO']
```